# Jquery exclude one event from on

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to do something like this

```
$('body').on('input !focus','.totalprice',function(){
   do something
}
```

actually I am clearing the value of input on focus so I want to exlude that case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('body').on(':not(click) change','#chkbox',function(){
   alert( event.type );
})
$('body').on(':not(focus) click keyup change','#chkbox1',function(){
   alert( event.type );
})
```

try this way

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9ovzbht1/1/)

Comment: @TejuMB isnt that what is needed?to exclude the focus event?

Comment: Thank You :not(focus) is all i was looking for

Answer (score 1):

Try with focus event

```
$('body').on('focus', 'input.totalprice', function(){
   $(this).val('');
});
```

I am not Sure you looking for `blur` event

```
$('body').on('blur', 'input.totalprice', function(){
   $(this).val('');
});
```

Comment: He wants to perform something when it's in non focus mode. 
Then how can you specify the focus function?

Comment: @TejuMB   Notice his words "actually I am clearing the value of input on focus so I want to exlude that case". he didn't know the code

Comment: Yes, `Blur` make some sense to me :-)

Comment: "actually I am clearing the value of input on focus so I want to exclude that case"
Is that means - He doesn't want to clear the value of input on focus?

Answer (score 0):

To clear the input field on focus, use

```
$('input').on('focusin', function() {
    this.value = '';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing called 'input !focus'

Focus event must be called as below

```
<input class="focusInput" type="text" value="one" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('focus', '.focusInput', function() {
        console.log('Focus');
    });
</script>
```